# Is it possible to query device state (ie. battery charge remaining) via ADB shell command?

Tags: android, adb

I'd like to find out various bits of information on an Android device's current status via ADB. Can it be done, and - if so - how?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this:
`adb shell dumpsys battery`

It gives all the battery details.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Its ok happy to help :-)

Comment: For Android Oreo, use `adb shell dumpsys batteryproperties`

Comment: I am not getting battery status ff there are N devices connected.
I am running `adb -s <device_id> dumpsys battery`. Did anyone get battery status for individual devices?

Comment: I think the `level` field in the output tells the battery status, i.e. `43` when the charge status is 43%.

Answer (score 10):

IF YOUR DEVICE IS ROOTED

You can use ADB almost like a remote shell, so you can get devices battery info using `adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_attr_text` where "level" is battery level or `adb shell dumpsys battery`.

`adb shell <your command>` will let you execute almost any linux command. Some commands are not available and must be installed (e.g. busybox).

[Source](http://virtuallyhyper.com/2012/12/find-out-battery-status-of-rooted-andoid-phone-using-adb/)

Comment: Ok, @VineethHolla was 2 minutes faster

Comment: Well I still appreciate your reply :-)

Comment: For me, the path was in `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity`

Answer (score 7):

Pretty simple and you don't need rooted device for this.
`adb shell dumpsys <option>`

Subsitute options with any of these:
battery
diskstats
wifi
location
usagestats
cpuinfo
iphonesubinfo
telephony.registry
meminfo
netstat
package

You may also try `adb shell dumpsys | grep "DUMP OF SERVICE"`
This will list many other options available with dumpsys.

Answer (score 1):

NO ROOTED NEED

Go straight forward

```
adb shell dumpsys battery
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Dump battery level

```bash
adb shell cmd battery get level
```

To customize the output:

```
adb shell cmd battery get level | sed 's/.*/Battery:&%/'
Battery:100%
```

Dump all settings for cmd battery (posix):

```
batstats="ac usb wireless status level temp present counter invalid"

for batstat in $batstats; do
  value=$(adb shell cmd battery get "$batstat")
  printf "%-8s: %s\n" "$batstat" "$value"
done
```

Output:

```
ac        : false
usb       : true
wireless  : false
status    : 5
level     : 100
temp      : 303
present   : true
counter   : 4512000
invalid   : 0
```

- Confirmed: android 13/12 - no root reuqired.

#### Dumpsys:

- equal to cmd

```bash
adb shell dumpsys battery get level
```

For the last command:

- [Is it possible to fetch current battery level via ADB shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73541991/is-it-possible-to-fetch-current-battery-level-via-adb-shell-command)

---

However, for your request the following example will do what you asking for:

```bash
adb logcat -d -s AODBatteryManager | tac | awk -F' ' '/mRemainingChargeTime/ {
    split($15, arr, "=")
    gsub(",", "", arr[2])
    minutes = int(arr[2] / 60000)
    seconds = int((arr[2] % 60000) / 1000)
    if (!found) {
        print "Estimated time until fully charged: " minutes " min " seconds " seconds"
        found=1
        exit
    }
}'
```

- Output

```
Estimated time until fully charged: 31 min 53 seconds
```

The command retrieves the log messages, reverses them, searches for the line containing "mRemainingChargeTime", extracts the relevant value, calculates the estimated time until fully charged in minutes and seconds, and prints the result. It ensures that only the first match is processed before exiting thats why I included "tac" so we skip the earlier messages since it is printed every ~10 seconds if monitoring the command, for doing that just add `adb logcat -c; adb logcat -s ...` and remove the tac and -d from the command:

```bash
# Clear old logs

adb logcat -c 

# Monitor remaining time

adb logcat -s AODBatteryManager  | awk -F' ' '/mRemainingChargeTime/ {
    split($15, arr, "=")
    gsub(",", "", arr[2])
    minutes = int(arr[2] / 60000)
    seconds = int((arr[2] % 60000) / 1000)
    if (!found) {
        print "Estimated time until fully charged: " minutes " min " seconds " seconds"
        found=1
        exit
    }
}'
Time left to full: 29min 29seconds
Time left to full: 29min 22seconds
Time left to full: 29min 11seconds
Time left to full: 29min 4seconds
Time left to full: 28min 57seconds
Time left to full: 28min 46seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
adb shell "dumpsys battery | grep level"
```