# Is it possible to fetch current battery level via ADB shell command?

Tags: android, adb, battery, dumpsys

Suppose If change the battery level to any desired value(say from current 50 to 20)

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set level 20
```

Now I want adb command to fetch the current battery level(ie 20).

With the below command I can reset to original value(50 in our example)

```
adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

Now again I want fetch the current current charge level via adb command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linux/macOS:

```
 adb shell dumpsys battery | grep level
```

For Windows:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery | findstr /r /c:level
```

Comment: Getting error with above command "grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: What OS are you on? Windows/Linux/macOS ?

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: try
 adb shell dumpsys battery | findstr /r /c:level

Comment: The easier solution would be to use grep of the Android phone:  `adb shell "dumpsys battery | grep level"` As it bases on Linux the chance is very high that it has grep.

Comment: Yes it also worked.. adb shell "dumpsys battery | grep level" @Robert

Comment: Is there any way to get only value say 50 instead of level:50? I have asked the question separately here, please reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557532/is-it-possible-to-get-value-for-current-battery-level-via-adb-shell-command