# Is it possible to get value for current battery level via ADB shell command?

Tags: android, adb, battery, dumpsys

With the below adb command I am able to get current battery level(as shown in image.

```
adb shell dumpsys battery | findstr /r /c:level
```

[image]

I am getting response as **level: 12**

Is there any way to get only value(ie 12 here) instead of level:12?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the commands available on Android to get the correct line and then get only the right side of the line:

```
adb shell "dumpsys battery | grep level | sed 's/^.* \(.*\)$/\1/' "
```

sed will output what is printed after the last space to the line end.