# Meta Quest Get controller battery level using ADB

Tags: android, adb, oculus

I'm working on a project to make controlling Meta Quest 2 (and probably 3 in the future) easier. As a part of this project I would like to be able to see what level the touch controllers are at. My initial thoughts it that it might be somewhere in dumpsys, but I couldn't see anything that jumped out at me

I can find the HMD battery information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274720/is-it-possible-to-query-device-state-ie-battery-charge-remaining-via-adb-shel) but it doesn't seem to give any information about the touch controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out controller data can be found using

```
adb shell dumpsys OVRRemoteService
```

putting this through grep, you can just get the connection and battery status of the controller using

```
adb shell "dumpsys OVRRemoteService | grep Paired"
```

(For reference found using `adb shell dumpsys` which dumps everything and serarching for "battery")